# How to find upper and lower bound without using formula?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

I am studying discrete math for tomorrow's exam and got stuck in the below question. I tried to google it and couldn't find anything usefull.

Prove the following sum is theta(n^2) (we have to find O(n^2) and omega (n^2))

1) $P(n)= 1+2+3+4+\cdots +n$

2) $P(n) =n+(n+1)+(n+2)+\cdots +2n$

Note: you **cannot** use any formula you have to do it my algebraic manipulation.

This might be simple but I am not getting any clue right now and I dont have solution of it.

Answer (score 3):

For $P(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n,$ there are $n$ terms on the right and none is
greater than $n,$ so $P(n) \leq n^2$ and therefore $P(n) = O(n^2).$
On the other hand, the last $\left\lceil \dfrac n2 \right\rceil$ terms 
are each at least $\dfrac n2$, so 
$P(n) \geq \left\lceil \dfrac n2 \right\rceil \left(\dfrac n2\right) \geq \dfrac{n^2}{4},$
and $P(n) = \Omega(n^2).$

Alternatively, observe that the first $\left\lfloor \dfrac n2 \right\rfloor$
terms can be paired with the last $\left\lfloor \dfrac n2 \right\rfloor$
like this: $1 + n,$ $2 + (n-1),$ $3 + (n-2),$ etc., so 
$P(n) \geq \left\lfloor \dfrac n2 \right\rfloor n.$
But this is very close to finding that $P(n) = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2},$ which you're
not supposed to do, so maybe that's not such a clever idea for this exam.

The reasoning for the other series is similar except that you don't have to do the trick with ignoring the first half of the series.

Answer (score 0):

1) Notice that $P(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \leq n^{2} \implies P(n) \in O(n^{2})$.

Or perhaps you would prefer: $P(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} n = n^{2}$. This gives you $P(n) \in O(n^{2})$.

Then you can show $n^{2} \leq 3P(n)$ to get $P(n) \in \Omega(n^{2})$.

2) Use the same trick. $P(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} (n + i) \leq \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2n = 2 \sum_{i=0}^{n} n = 2n^{2}$. Then just apply the techniques from part (1).

Answer (score 0):

For 1) if $n = 2k$, then $P(n) = P(2k) = 1+2+3+\cdots + 2k = (1+2k) +(2+ (2k-1)) + (3+(2k-2)) + \cdots + (k+(2k-(k-1))) = (2k+1) +(2k+1) + \cdots + (2k+1) = k(2k+1) = \dfrac{n}{2}\cdot (n+1) = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

If $n = 2k+1$, then:

$1 + 2 + 3 +\cdots + (2k+1) = (1+2+3+\cdots + 2k) + (2k+1) = (1+2+\cdots + +(n-1)) + n = \dfrac{(n-1)n}{2} + n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

For 2) $n + (n+1) + (n+2) +\cdots + 2n = (n+n+n+\cdots + n) + (1+2+3+\cdots + n) = n\cdot n + \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} = n^2 + \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Comment: Thats what came into my head before but the question clearly says you cannot use any equations including arithmetic sum formula.